# Python: When non-integer is entered into input program crashes

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im making a program for my intro to python class project. Its a pokedex. I have everything setup but my friend brought up the fact that when he entered any non number or number over 151 would crash the program. I tried to do an `elif` statement to see if it `isalpha()` but when i tried it, it would print this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 712, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

so i just need help stopping it from crashing when it has any input thats not valid. the full prgram is on this [Link](https://repl.it/EzIi/22)

```
#should define it here 
def print_userpoke_details(userpoke):
#take a parameter,the user input

    if userpoke == 1:
        print(Bulbasaur)
    elif userpoke.isalpha():
        print ("You did not enter a valid number")

while True:
    userpoke = input("Pokémon #:")
    #call the function here with user input
    print_userpoke_details(userpoke)
```

Comment: fix your indentation please and keep in mind that whatever is passed from `input` is automatically converted into string. Even if it is a number so it would not be `5` for example but `'5'`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis no it isn't, OP is evidently using Python 2 where input evaluates its contents.

Comment: @DanielRoseman How do you know that? The `print` is parenthesised

Comment: Because that is the error you get when you use input with a string in Python 2, see the linked duplicate.

Comment: According to the `repl.it` link, OP is using v2.7

Comment: @Ev.Kounis parenthesised `print` works in both  Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: @abukaj That i know but not many people used to parenthesise prints back then